# Elastic search synchronization with relational database?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say have a sql server which is imported in elastic search using JDBC importer.
As elastic search will just be used for the search purpose and transactions being handled by the sql server .

How it could be made sure that all changes to sql server either create,delete or update also reflects to data in elastic search .
Any turn around , if there will also help.